# Stop Tumblr from adding JS and CSS files to theme

Tags: tumblr

Tumblr is just flooding the blogs with loads of JS and CSS files. I don't know if these files are required or just useful. Here's a list of them

The JS:
 - tumblelog.js & pre_tumblelog.js -> looks like this is Tumblr JS API, but do we need it?
 - cedexis.radar.js -> no idea what this does.
 - rapid-3.18.1.js

The CSS:

- fonts/gibson/stylesheet.css

And some images are also added to the page.

I searched a bit, but there is no way of stopping tumblr from doing this.
Is there any way we can stop Tumblr from doing so, if we don't need these files?
If we need the scripts, can you please elaborate why we need these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sadly you can't do anything to stop Tumblr adding scripts / style sheets as they are added serverside.

For reference, `fonts/gibson/stylesheet.css` is added in relation to the theme fonts option: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#theme-options

Comment: thank you for confirming that to me. My theme does not have custom fonts option and still it adds gibson/stylesheet.css

Comment: I clarified my answer. Its added automagically and we have no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to *break* some of the scripts (for example by adding `window.addEventListener = 1`), but it's probably not be worth the hassle.

You can remove any extra CSS or element via javascript but any downloads initiated by them can't be prevented.